# How can I share more DNA with a distant cousin's son than with the distant cousin?

Tags: dna

My Heritage has brought up a 0.6% match with a suggested son of a 3rd Cousin / 4th Cousin.  He is aged under 20.
Their tree is managed by the father aged in his 40's.  However, there is only a 0.2% reported DNA match with the father.
For the son there are 2 shared segments of DNA, the largest being on chromosome 3 of 32.9CM.
For the father there is only 1 shared segment for 12.9CM on chromosome 3 which falls within the range I share with the son.
The father and son are a 49.7% match.
Can anyone suggest how this might be?  For instance might this be due to inaccurate results produced by My Heritage?

Answer (score 4):

If accurate, it most likely means that you are related to both the match's mother and father.